# Change classes in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, refactoring, multiple-inheritance

I have a class ImageA, and a class ImageB. The both classes represents an image in my app, but each one in a different way. Even being different, their constructors are equal, and both have the method **compare**.

So, what I done was creating a class Image, and ImageA and ImageB are subClasses of Image.

```
public abstract class Image {
    protected String path;

    public Image(String path){
        this.path = path;
    }

    public abstract double compare(Image i2);
}


public class ImageA extends Image{...} 

public class ImageB extends Image{...}
```

But what I need is to test each implementation of image (ImageA and ImageB, in this case), to see the best one.

Is there a way to do this, changing my code at minimum? Suppose the objects used are from ImageA class, and I want to test now imageB class;

Obs.:

- If all imageA objects of my app are
  setted by the type (ImageA i = new
  ImageA()), I'd have to change
  manually all in the code.
- But even if I use the superType and
  cast it (Image i = (ImageA)new
  Image()), I'll have the same problem,
  to change the casts.
- My question is different from this one: [Refactoring abstract Java class with many child classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456629/refactoring-abstract-java-class-with-many-child-classes) . In my case, the attributes inside the child classes are different, and I keep the attributes common to these classes in the Image class.

Comment: IDEs like Eclipse can replace every `ImageA` in your project when you change its name.

Comment: I didn't get the question. Please re-read it yourself and make it more clear

Comment: @Bozho, I made some small changes, but I don't know they are enough. Sorry about my english, but it's the best I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a factory and pass an instance of your factory into the test class, using:

```
Image img = factory.newInstance(args);
```

throughout your test code. The factory determines which of the types ImageA or ImageB is used. An alternative would be to have a `abstract Image newInstance(args)` in your `Image` class and implement it in your subclasses. You would inject a first image instance into your test classes in that case.

Both methods rely on the fact that your args are the same between both types of images, you might need to pass in a superset to fulfill both constructors.

Answer (score 3):

If this is an option (maybe I didn't get the question), you should use a [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to get the proper concrete class. The pizza sample is self explaining:

```
abstract class Pizza {
    public abstract int getPrice(); // count the cents
}

class HamAndMushroomPizza extends Pizza {
    public int getPrice() {
        return 850;
    }
}

class DeluxePizza extends Pizza {
    public int getPrice() {
        return 1050;
    }
}

class HawaiianPizza extends Pizza {
    public int getPrice() {
        return 1150;
    }
}

class PizzaFactory {
    public enum PizzaType {
        HamMushroom,
        Deluxe,
        Hawaiian
    }

    public static Pizza createPizza(PizzaType pizzaType) {
        switch (pizzaType) {
            case HamMushroom:
                return new HamAndMushroomPizza();
            case Deluxe:
                return new DeluxePizza();
            case Hawaiian:
                return new HawaiianPizza();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The pizza type " + pizzaType + " is not recognized.");
    }
}

class PizzaLover {
    /*
     * Create all available pizzas and print their prices
     */
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        for (PizzaFactory.PizzaType pizzaType : PizzaFactory.PizzaType.values()) {
            System.out.println("Price of " + pizzaType + " is " + PizzaFactory.createPizza(pizzaType).getPrice());
        }
    }
}

Output:
Price of HamMushroom is 850
Price of Deluxe is 1050
Price of Hawaiian is 1150
```

Answer (score 1):

I have some difficulty in understanding your question. I try here to summarize your problem statement,please comment if this is indeed what your question is.
(I would have put this as a comment but the number of characters exceed 600)

You have classes `ImageA` and `ImageB` that are subclasses of `Image`

Constructor for both these classes is the same and accepts a path argument 
 (which I presume to be the path of image file)

Classes `ImageA` and `ImageB` use different attributes to represent the image

Common attributes classes `ImageA` and `ImageB` are kept in the base class (like the path attribute)

You declare an abstract method `compare` which takes an `Image` type as argument and 
returns a double value

The goal is to pass to compare method of `ImageA` a type of `ImageB` and the return value would indicate which concrete image representation is better. So this would mean that implementation of `compare` method should be such that, `compare` method in class `ImageA` will be called with instance of type `ImageB` and viceversa will be the implementation in class `ImageB`

The compare method in classes `ImageA` and `ImageB` cannot use methods in `Image` since they have different attributes

If this problem statement indeed represents your problem, then I think is without resorting to checks like `instanceof` and casting it won't be possible to do the comparison between classes `ImageA` and `ImageB`. Though there is an abstract class `Image` the `compare` method still depends on what image attributes (which are not the same) the child classes use to represent an image.